# Socket closed before recv without calling close

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying a C program to accept OAuth 2 authcode from Google Server (in the form of a HTTP GET request). If I try to read using recv(), it throws the error, **Transport endpoint is not connected** . This is only after I receive a non-negative integer after accept() call. I have tried the same using Java and Netcat utility, both work fine for me.

Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/select.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>

void *send_authcode_request(void *sockaddr_ptr);

int main() {
    char *bind_addr = "127.0.0.1";
    char *errmsg = (char *) malloc(1024);
    short int port = 0;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in local_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_port = port;
    inet_aton(bind_addr, &(local_addr.sin_addr));
    memset(&(local_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

    int sock_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    /*fcntl(sock_id, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);*/

    if (bind(sock_id, (struct sockaddr*) &local_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        sprintf(errmsg, "Cannot bind socket to the port #%d", port);
        perror(errmsg);
        return -1;
    }
    if (listen(sock_id, 20) == -1) {
        sprintf(errmsg, "Cannot listen to connections on the socket");
        perror(errmsg);
        return -1;
    }
    int sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if(getsockname(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *) &local_addr, &sin_size) == -1) {
        sprintf(errmsg, "Unable to get the current address of the socket");
        perror(errmsg);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\n Port no after binding #%d\n", ntohs(local_addr.sin_port));

    pthread_t authcode_req_thread;
    pthread_create(&authcode_req_thread, NULL, send_authcode_request, (void *) &local_addr);

    fd_set read_fs;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fs);
    FD_SET(sock_id, &read_fs);

    long accept_timeout = 60*10;

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = accept_timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    char auth_code_info[1024];

    if (select(sock_id+1, &read_fs, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0) {
        /*if(accept4(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_size, SOCK_NONBLOCK) == -1) {*/
        if(accept(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_size) >= 0) {
            /* Accept auth code */
            int bytesread;
            if ((bytesread = recv(sock_id, auth_code_info, 1023, 0)) == -1) {
                perror(errmsg);
                return -1;
            }
            printf("\n%s\n", auth_code_info);
            char *reply = "Done! You can now close the window";
            send(sock_id, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
        } else {
            sprintf(errmsg, "No client connected within timeout of %ld seconds", accept_timeout);
            perror(errmsg);
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        sprintf(errmsg, "No client connected within timeout of %ld seconds", accept_timeout);
        perror(errmsg);
        return -1;
    }
    close(sock_id);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void *send_authcode_request(void *ptr) {
    char *scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    char *client_id = "1098482466406-c3h15ld90l03s0pl4rm7qq54fcb49t78.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const char *temp_authcode_uri = "xdg-open \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=%s&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:%d&response_type=code&client_id=%s\"";

    struct sockaddr_in *socket_address = (struct sockaddr_in *) ptr;

    int max_authcode_uri_len = strlen(temp_authcode_uri) + strlen(client_id) + strlen(scope);
    char *authcode_uri = (char *) malloc(max_authcode_uri_len);
    sprintf(authcode_uri, temp_authcode_uri, scope, ntohs(socket_address->sin_port), client_id);
    printf("\n%s\n", authcode_uri);
    system(authcode_uri);
}
```

However, when I listen to the same port using **netcat**, it displays the HTTP request from the browser. So I traced the TCP traffic for the port using Wireshark and found one traffic different than what I get when using netcat.

## For my program

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000000    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     48234 → 49927 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7268636 TSecr=0 WS=128
      2 0.000010715    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     49927 → 48234 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7268636 TSecr=7268636 WS=128
      3 0.000020978    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     48234 → 49927 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268636 TSecr=7268636
      4 0.000059901    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     48236 → 49927 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7268636 TSecr=0 WS=128
      5 0.000064624    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     49927 → 48236 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7268636 TSecr=7268636 WS=128
      6 0.000070536    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     48236 → 49927 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268636 TSecr=7268636
      7 0.000384302    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     49927 → 48234 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268636 TSecr=7268636
      8 0.000412860    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     49927 → 48236 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268636 TSecr=7268636
      9 0.000997709    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     48234 → 49927 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268637 TSecr=7268636
     10 0.000974316    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     [TCP Keep-Alive] 48234 → 49927 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268637 TSecr=7268636
     11 0.001005630    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     49927 → 48234 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=2 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7268637 TSecr=7268637
     12 0.001047174    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     48238 → 49927 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7268637 TSecr=0 WS=128
     13 0.001051855    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      54     49927 → 48238 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
     14 0.237652758    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     48240 → 49927 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7268696 TSecr=0 WS=128
     15 0.237664760    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      54     49927 → 48240 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
     16 5.243733213    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     48242 → 49927 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7269947 TSecr=0 WS=128
     17 5.243751969    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      54     49927 → 48242 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

## when using netcat

Using netcat, I get the needed HTTP Get request containing the authentication token.

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000000    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     45064 → 2807 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7233868 TSecr=0 WS=128
      2 0.000008155    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     2807 → 45064 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7233868 TSecr=7233868 WS=128
      3 0.000015895    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     45064 → 2807 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7233868 TSecr=7233868
      4 0.000043941    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     45066 → 2807 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7233868 TSecr=0 WS=128
      5 0.000047566    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      74     2807 → 45066 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=7233868 TSecr=7233868 WS=128
      6 0.000050911    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     45066 → 2807 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7233868 TSecr=7233868
      7 0.000074583    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     2807 → 45066 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7233868 TSecr=7233868
      8 0.000833585    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             HTTP     654    GET /?code=4/zuPKCQlOvIcJq5gAvPRGLQdkiICNzOmAQUAx9apK5go HTTP/1.1 
      9 0.000841060    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     2807 → 45064 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=589 Win=44928 Len=0 TSval=7233868 TSecr=7233868
     10 45.005118503   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     [TCP Keep-Alive] 45064 → 2807 [ACK] Seq=588 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=0 TSval=7245120 TSecr=7233868
     11 45.005166221   127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2807 → 45064 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=589 Win=44928 Len=0 TSval=7245120 TSecr=7233868
```

As you can see, my program sends a FIN flag, which is not there in netcat. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: @Olaf I wouldn't exactly call a Wireshark screenshot an image of text.  You can't just copy/paste the packet listing, not easily at least.

Comment: @dbush: You can dump it to a textfile (not sure if it is even possible to dump to the clipboard).

Comment: @dbush thanks. Dumping as text was pretty easy. File -> Export Packet Dissections -> As Plain Text. In the export window, we can select which details to export. Just learnt it after Olaf asked to paste text dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading from the wrong socket.

The socket that you pass to `listen` is a listening socket only.  It does not represent a connected socket.  It is identified by only a local IP and port.

When you call `accept`, this function returns the file descriptor of the connected socket.  These sockets are identified by a local IP and port as well as a remote IP and port.  This function can therefore be called multiple times for multiple incoming connections, each with its own socket.  That way, you can deal with connections from multiple endpoints.

Save the return value of `accept` as a new socket, and use that one to `send` and `recv` on.  Be sure to `close` it when you're done.